# How do I create a parallel loop?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

You'd think this would be simple question, but I can't find the solution. Take the following loop:

```
A = zeros(1,10000000);
parfor i = 1:length(A)
    A(i) = i;
end
```

This only runs on a single core on my computer, although it's readily parallelisable (or at least it should be). I am using Matlab 2012b, and I've tried looking for documentation on how to create parallel loops but can't find any (the matlab docs just show examples of how to create these loops, not how to actually run them in parallel).

I've tried looking up how to modify parallel computing toolbox settings, but none of them work since they're all for Matlab 2013 (I'm using 2012b). If someone could provide an example of a trivial, parallelisable loop that *actually runs in parallel* I would be very grateful!

Note: I have checked and the parallel computing toolbox is installed, although I have no way of knowing if it is enabled, or how to enable it, since the documentation doesn't seem to provide an answer to this for my version (I typed `preferences` into the command prompt but didn't see it there).

EDIT: I got it working by doing this:

```
matlabpool('open',4);
A = zeros(1,10000000);
parfor i = 1:length(A)
    A(i) = i;
end
matlabpool('close');
```

... but I don't really know why this works, whether I have close the pool every time, what a pool actually is (I've read the [documnentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/distcomp/parpool.html), still don't get it), and how `matlabpool` differs from `parpool`...

Comment: maybe you meant `A(i)=i`, now you're just overwriting the same variable over and over and after the loop, `A` will just be equal to `10000000`.

Comment: @GuntherStruyf sorry that was a typo; code was correct when I tested it.

Comment: Did you check `parpool`? It's in the "see also" section of the `parfor` documentation: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/distcomp/parpool.html

Comment: @sebastian - `Undefined function or variable 'parpool'. `

Comment: probably `matlabpool open`

Comment: PARPOOL is simply the new name for MATLABPOOL. It has an object-based API rather than the functional API of MATLABPOOL.

Comment: I would also add - don't close the MATLABPOOL unless you don't intend to run any further PARFOR loops in a given client session (perhaps unless the workers are consuming shared resources on a cluster where you might be advised to be more conservative)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, you need to launch the MATLAB workers:

```
matlabpool open N
```

The `parpool` command [replaced the `matlabpool` command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/release-notes.html) in version R2013b.  The command creates a number of local workers (assuming your default cluster is the `local` profile), which are simply MATLAB.exe processes running without a GUI, that execute parts of parallelized code, like your `parfor` loop.

Comment: Nit-pick: whether PARPOOL opens local workers or not depends on where your default configuration points. If you have only PCT, then it's true you only have access to local workers. If you have MDCS too, then you can run workers on a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary needed to close the pool. In some cases you may wish to keep it open for later reuse (as opening also takes some time). Testing for a zero pool size can be helpful to decide, if a new matlabpool needs to be open:

```
A = zeros(1,10000000);
if matlabpool('size') == 0 
   matlabpool('open',4) ;
end
parfor i = 1:length(A)
    A(i) = i;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the change from `matlabpool` to `parpool`, there is an even easier way to create the pool. Unlike `parpool`, it doesn't throw an error if the pool already exists. Just call `gcp` (which stands for "get current pool").

```
gcp();
A = zeros(1,10000000);
parfor i = 1:length(A)
    A(i) = i;
end
```

It is good practice to always leave the pool open; this just ensures that it's open when you need it.